# Extending a Ralyxa to manage different locales and directives

Tags: ruby, sinatra, metaprogramming, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently trying to extends the [Ralyxa gem](https://github.com/sjmog/ralyxa) to support multiple languages in the intents as well the directives.

The basic idea is something like this:

```rb
intent "SendMessage" do
  locale 'es-MX' do
    respond("es-MX")
  end
  locale 'en-IN' do
    respond("en-IN")
  end
end
```

I discovered that the feature need to be implemented somehow in the https://github.com/sjmog/ralyxa/blob/master/lib/ralyxa/skill.rb, but I am not yet sure where I should add such feature since is a subset of commands of intent.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome that you want to add locale handling to Ralyxa. You might want to add a `locale` method here: https://github.com/sjmog/ralyxa/blob/master/lib/ralyxa/handler.rb

All the intent methods, like `respond`, `tell` and `card` are defined here - you may need to define a `locale` method taking a block, which constructs a special `Ralyxa::Handler` instance for that locale.

Happy to review a Pull Request if you get round to implementing it!

(If you didn’t want to modify the base Ralyxa code, you might be able to simply use an `if...else` block to redirect the control flow depending on the locale.)